# xmlhttpRequest status returns 0 in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am making a hybrid app in phonegap. I am parsing json using xmlhttpRequest.My Problem is that when i try to fetch the response on browser,http.status is 200 and response is ok but when i try to run the code on android device then http.readystate comes out to be 4 but http.status comes 0 and i get empty response .I have searched many links and used CORPS also but the problem still persist. Can any one please tell me that how can i get the http.status as 200 on android device? Below is my code.

```
function myFunction(){
 alert("inside function");
 var http;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    alert(" inside if");
 }
 else
 {
     // code for IE6, IE5
     alert("inside else");
     http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
    var url = "http://localserver/abc/v1/signup";
    var params = "email=adsefgbbgtrhtrh &password=tyujkuykyuil &phone=95876894760458 ";
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4) {
            alert("inside if"+http.responseText); //Here i get empty text
        }
        alert("inside if function"+http.status+"state"+http.readyState);  //Here http.status is 0 and readystate is 4 
    }
    http.send(params);
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
    alert("ouside if"+http.status+"state"+http.readyState);}
```

On server side i have added to lines:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

I have also set the access origin in config.xml

```
<access origin="*"  subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="http://localserverIP*" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true"/>
```

please help!

Comment: status 0 is OK on phonegap apps, but if the response is empty then there is something wrong, probably related to the whitelist plugin or the content security policy meta tag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used XMLHttpRequest. So I used $.ajax and everything was working. I know that $.ajax is based on XMLHttpRequest, but it works and the development is more easy. I hope it helps even if the answer is a bit late. =)